# python fastapi large json request are relativly slow

Tags: python, json, fastapi

I have a simple service that gets a json and returns a json, those jsons are relativly large ~200Kb-~300Kb.
Now I noticed that even if I don't do any processing on the json it still takes about 30-40 Milli seconds the full round trip (even from my own machine).

Here is my code:

```
from typing import Dict

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(title="My test")

@app.post("/large_json_test")
async def foo(request: dict) -> dict:
    something = request.get("something") or "NA"
    x = "whatever" + something
    return {"request": request, "x": x}
```

when running the following bash:

```
time curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:8080/large_json_test" -d @large.json  -H "Content-Type: application/json" 1> /dev/null
```

returns the following results:

```
0.00s user 0.00s system 15% cpu 0.043 total
```

can also be 0.050 or so in total time!

Any suggestions of how can I make this faster?

Worth mentioning, when running with a small json request it will take 10Millis, which means that reading serializing and writing back the json takes about 30 - 40 milli seconds.

Comment: What makes you think it can GO faster?  Even a local "ping" takes tens of milliseconds.  300kBytes in 30ms is 10MB/s.  Even on a local machine, you're passing all that data through your network stack.

Comment: When there is no data it is much faster, maybe I should add this

Comment: You should look into custom response encoders and then use orjson, ujson or rapidjson. I think fastapi just uses the normal json lib which is quite slow.

Comment: I tried using orjson and ujson, only on the read side, and it did not moved the niddle, maybe I should try on the response side as well

Answer (score 1):

So as [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) suggested adding building the response using `orjson` or `ujson` make it significantly faster

code:

```
@app.post("/large_json_test1")
async def foo1(request: dict) -> Response:
    something = request.get("something") or "NA"
    x = "whatever" + something
    res = {"request": request, "x": x}
    return Response(
        content=ujson.dumps(res)
    )

@app.post("/large_json_test2")
async def foo2(request: dict) -> Response:
    something = request.get("something") or "NA"
    x = "whatever" + something
    res = {"request": request, "x": x}
    return Response(
        content=orjson.dumps(res)
    )
```

results:

**ujson**

```
curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:8080/large_json_test1" -d @large.json -H  >   0.00s user 0.00s system 43% cpu 0.014 total
```

**orjson**

```
curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:8080/large_json_test2" -d @example_session.json -H  >   0.00s user 0.00s system 41% cpu 0.016 total
```