# FastAPI is very slow in returning a large amount of JSON data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, fastapi

I have a FastAPI `GET` endpoint that is returning a large amount of JSON data (~160,000 rows and 45 columns). Unsurprisingly, it is *extremely* slow to return the data using `json.dumps()`. I am first reading the data from a file using `json.loads()` and filtering it per the inputted parameters. Is there a faster way to return the data to the user than using `return data`? It takes nearly a minute in the current state.

My code currently looks like this:

```py
# helper function to parse parquet file (where data is stored)
def parse_parquet(file_path):
    df = pd.read_parquet(file_path)
    result = df.to_json(orient = 'records')
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    return parsed
    

@app.get('/endpoint')
# has several more parameters
async def some_function(year = int | None = None, id = str | None = None):
    if year is None:
        data = parse_parquet(f'path/{year}_data.parquet')
    # no year
    if year is not None:
        data = parse_parquet(f'path/all_data.parquet')
    if id is not None:
        data = [d for d in data if d['id'] == id]
    return data
```

Comment: How much time does your `parse_parquet` function take?

Comment: @Jeril negligible time. The timing issue is on returning the data as a json

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221272/python-fastapi-large-json-request-are-relativly-slow about how to use alternative json encoders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the reasons for the response being that slow is that in your `parse_parquet()` method, you initially convert the file into JSON (using `df.to_json()`), then into dictionary (using `json.loads()`) and finally into JSON again, as FastAPI, behind the scenes, [automatically converts](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/) the returned value into JSON-compatible data using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), and then uses the Python standard `json.dumps()` to serialise the object—a process that is quite slow (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details).

As suggested by @MatsLindh in the comments section, you could use alternative JSON encoders, such as [orjson](https://github.com/ijl/orjson) or [ujosn](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804) as well), which would indeed speed up the process, compared to letting FastAPI use the `jsonable_encoder` and then the standard `json.dumps()` for converting the data into JSON. **However**, using pandas [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and returing a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response) directly—as described in **Option 1** (**Update 2**) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804)—seems to be the best-performing solution. You can use the code given below—which uses a [custom `APIRoute` class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router)—to compare the response time for all available solutions.

Use your own parquet file or the below code to create a sample parquet file consisting of 160K rows and 45 columns.

**create_parquet.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['C' + str(i) for i in range(1, 46)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(99999, 99999999, size=(160000,45)),columns=columns)
df.to_parquet('data.parquet')
```

Run the FastAPI app below and access each endpoint separately to inspect the time taken to complete the process of loading and converting the data into JSON.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Response, Request
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from typing import Callable
import pandas as pd
import json
import time
import ujson
import orjson


class TimedRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            before = time.time()
            response: Response = await original_route_handler(request)
            duration = time.time() - before
            response.headers["Response-Time"] = str(duration)
            print(f"route duration: {duration}")
            return response

        return custom_route_handler

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=TimedRoute)

@router.get("/defaultFastAPIencoder")
def get_data_default():
    df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet')   
    return df.to_dict(orient="records")
    
@router.get("/orjson")
def get_data_orjson():
    df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet')
    return Response(orjson.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records')), media_type="application/json")

@router.get("/ujson")
def get_data_ujson():
    df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet')   
    return Response(ujson.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records')), media_type="application/json")

# Preferred way  
@router.get("/pandasJSON")
def get_data_pandasJSON():
    df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet')   
    return Response(df.to_json(orient="records"), media_type="application/json")  

app.include_router(router)
```

Even though the response time is quite fast using `/pandasJSON` above (and this should be the preferred way), you may encounter some delay on displaying the data on the browser. That, however, has nothing to do with the server side, but with the client side, as the browser is trying to display a large amount of data. If you don't want to display the data, but instead let the user download the data to their device (which would be much faster), you can set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header in the `Response` using the `attachment` parameter and passing a `filename` as well, indicating to the browser that the file should be downloaded. For more details, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804).

```py
@router.get("/download")
def get_data():
    df = pd.read_parquet('data.parquet')
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="data.json"'}
    return Response(df.to_json(orient="records"), headers=headers, media_type='application/json')
```

I should also mention that there is a library, called [`Dask`](https://github.com/dask/dask/), which can handle large datasets, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719352/17865804), in case you had to process a large amount of records that is taking too long to complete. Similar to Pandas, you can use the [`.read_parquet()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html) method to read the file. As Dask doesn't seem to provide an equivalent `.to_json()` method, you could convert the Dask DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame using [`df.compute()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.compute.html), and then use Pandas `df.to_json()` to convert the DataFrame into a JSON string, and return it as demonstrated above.

I would also suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804), which provides details and solutions on streaming/returning a DataFrame, in case that you are dealing with a large amount of data that converting them into JSON (using [`.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)) or CSV (using [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)) may cause memory issues on server side, if you opt to store the output string (either JSON or CSV) into RAM (which is the default behaviour, if you don't pass a *path* parameter to the aforementioned functions)—since a large amount of memory would already be allocated for the original DataFrame as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `json.loads(result)` will return a dict data type in your case, and you are filtering the dict data type. You can send the dict data type as JSON as follows:

```
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.get('/endpoint')
# has several more parameters
async def some_function(year = int | None = None, id = str | None = None):
    if year is None:
        data = parse_parquet(f'path/{year}_data.parquet')
    # no year
    if year is not None:
        data = parse_parquet(f'path/all_data.parquet')
    if id is not None:
        data = [d for d in data if d['id'] == id]
    return JSONResponse(content=json_compatible_item_data)
```